# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments when trying to build from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to build my application in Heroku and I'm getting this error on the logs:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9:in `add_modifier'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/type.rb:27:in `add_modifier'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:834:in `<class:PostgreSQLAdapter>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:72:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:22:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:191:in `spec'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:950:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in on_load'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `on_load'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:132:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_575f45fc/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

Here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# rails
gem 'rails', '5.2.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'pg'

# gem 'mini_racer'

gem 'puma'
gem "puma_worker_killer"

gem 'net-ssh'
gem 'sprockets'

gem 'sys-proctable'
gem 'tzinfo-data'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2'

# error tracking
gem 'rollbar'

# assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

# -------------------------------
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'slim-rails'
# -------------------------------

gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 6.0.0'

# forms
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'link_to_add_fields'

# meta tags
gem 'meta-tags'


# Parse xls files
gem "roo"

# Create pdf grid
gem 'prawn', '~> 2.1'
gem 'prawn-templates', '~> 0.0.4'

# Create Carrousel
gem "jquery-slick-rails"
# spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/jonleighton/spring
group :development do
  gem 'spring', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem "bullet"
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem "aws-sdk"
  gem "rb-readline"
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
end

# authentication
gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/heartcombo/devise', branch: 'main'


# access levels
gem 'cancancan'


# friendly urls
gem 'friendly_id'

# custom validation for urls
gem 'validate_url'

# keeps session in active record so session can be bigger than 4kb
gem 'activerecord-session_store'

gem 'kaminari'

group :test, :development do
  # specs
  gem 'rspec-rails'

  # interactive debug
  # gem 'pry-rails'

  # javascript specs
  gem 'jasmine-rails'

  # jquery for javascript specs
  gem 'jasmine-jquery-rails'
end

group :test do

  # test coverage
  gem 'simplecov'

  # feature specs
  gem 'launchy'
end

gem 'ckeditor', "~> 4.2.4"
# gem 'redactor-rails'
gem 'sitemap_generator'

gem 'business_time'
gem 'holidays'

gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'premailer-rails'
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'inline_svg'

gem 'wrgem'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
gem 'correios-frete'
gem 'correios-cep'
gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 0.9.9", :require => ['zip/zip', 'zip/zipfilesystem']
gem 'sidekiq'

gem 'raygun4ruby'

gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'

gem 'tinyerp_ruby'

gem 'ransack', '~> 2.1'
gem 'rmagick'


gem 'rack-tracker'

gem "jquery_context_menu-rails"

gem 'rails_autoscale_agent'

gem 'heroku-deflater', :group => :production

gem 'canonical-rails', github: 'jumph4x/canonical-rails'


gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'facebookbusiness', '~> 0.11.0.0'

gem 'axlsx'

# performance analytics
gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 6.7.0.359'

# gem 'rqrcode'

gem "figaro"

gem 'rest-client'
gem 'pagarme'

gem "paranoia", "~> 2.2"

gem 'chartkick'
gem 'groupdate'

gem 'recaptcha'

gem 'nokogiri'

# Use react on rails
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'react-rails'

# -------
# API

# Auth
gem 'jwt'
gem 'simple_command'

# Serializers
gem 'fast_jsonapi'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.10'
gem 'active_model_serializers-jsonapi_embedded_records_deserializer'

# Clone active_record objects
gem 'amoeba'

# QR code
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'mimemagic', '~> 0.3.6'

gem 'lazyload-rails'

gem 'active_link_to'

gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'active-campaign-rails'

gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]

gem 'sprockets_better_errors', groups: [:development, :test]
```

I have tried downgrading rails version, changing ransack version but nothing works, I still cannot build the project, It works fine on my localhost, but Heroku just won't build.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. For those who are getting this, you must specify the rails version to '2.5.3' in the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.5.3"
```

Comment: I think you meant to say that we must specify the _ruby_ version (and not the rails version)?